# Inorganic Limestone and Inorganic Gypsum

Tags: rocks, mineralogy, sedimentology

I read that limestone is made from the compaction of marine animals' bones. But, I am unable to find out why limestone could not have been produced from [calcium occurring naturally (5th most abundant element in earth's crust) in the Earth Crust and in the mantle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_elements_in_Earth%27s_crust)

Is gypsum also produced from marine animal's bones?

Comment: Related: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/in-an-earth-like-planet-with-no-history-of-carbon-based-life-forms-would-there and https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/formation-of-limestone-without-living-organisms

Answer (score 1):

Limestone is a sedimentary rock made up mainly of the mineral calcite (calcium carbonate). It may be made up of biogenic calcite such as shells or inorganic calcite deposited as fine grained "[micrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micrite)" although some micrite may also have a biological origin.

Animals don't have bones made from gypsum so all gypsum deposits have non-biological origin.

Comment: Where does the Calcium in Gypsum come from? Is it from the bones of marine animals?